# Multi color progress bar Android

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar

I know that this question has been asked but i could not figure out my problem.
I want to create a progress bar which will have three colors during the progress.
It will starts with blue, after 40% of progress it will smoothly turns to orange and after 75% it will turns smoothly to red.

I have a drawable for the background and a single color for the progress:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/background">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#666666"
            android:centerColor="#808080"
            android:endColor="#999999"
            android:centerY="1.0"
            android:angle="270"/>
        <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@+id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#0099e6"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

I create my progress bar dynamically:

```
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbar_style);
    progressBar.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
    progressBar.setMax(100);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 60){
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
                });
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                progressStatus++;
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: What is the result? An error? Please be more specific.

Comment: The result is a progress bar with one color!
I want a progress bar with three colors as i described!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thae the only think i did was to set the 
android:angle ="0".

Answer (score 0):

Use this to multicolor in progress bar (https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar)